# Knockout afterAdd function not firing on preloaded items

Tags: knockout.js

I've encountered a problem with knockout when using the foreach binding with an 'afterAdd' function return. Basically, it doesn't fire when initially calling ko.applyBindings - if items are subsequently added to the foreach data it works.

Here's a simple fiddle to demonstrate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/sWa3F/1/

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: items, afterAdd: function(a,b,c) { $(a).css('color', 'red'); }}">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = {
            items: ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C'])
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    vm.items.push('D');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is quite clear... `afterAdd` happens after adding the elements. So if they existed before the binding, `afterAdd` won't be called. That should be obvious.

So, why don't you first bind the model, and then add the items to your observable array, i.e.

```
var vm = {
        items: ko.observableArray()
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
// preload items after binding:
vm.items(['A', 'B', 'C']); // afterAdd will be called!!
vm.items.push('D');
```

Alternatively you can use `afterRender` ([docs here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)):

> afterRender — is invoked each time the foreach block is duplicated and inserted into the document, both when foreach first initializes, and when new entries are added to the associated array later. Knockout will supply the following parameters to your callback:
>
> - An array of the inserted DOM elements
> - The data item against which they are being bound

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for that. My question looks very stupid now. afterRender is what I actually needed.

Comment: Take it easy! We all make these kind of silly mistakes all the time.